# message.mentions sometimes return empty

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Discord.py's `ctx.message.mentions` doesn't work with string after it.

For example:

Me: ban @MEE6

works perfectly fine, it can detect that I mentioned a name and everything
but

Me: ban @MEE6 please

doesn't work, it doesn't even detect that I mentioned a person
Is there a problem on my end, is this supposed to happen??

Also, I'm not looking for an argument I add in my function, I'm looking to use `ctx.message.mentions`

Comment: If u could send the code which u coded it would be easy for us to slove

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mentions are passed explicitly by Discord API along with the message event, discord.py does not attempt to parse it manually from the message. As long as the target of the mention gets pinged, it'll be present in `message.mentions`.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object-message-structure

What I suspect is when you typed "ban @MEE6 please", you pinged MEE6's role instead of the bot user (which can happen when you copied the previous message "ban @MEE6"). If you checked [`message.role_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Message.role_mentions) as well, you should find the mention there (if you have the proper permissions to ping).

discord.py also has [`Message.raw_mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=logging#discord.Message.raw_mentions) which parses all user mentions directly from message instead of being provided by the API.